# Is there a way of generating API documentation with 'validate' on 'request' in action's method using dedoc/scramble?

Tags: laravel, domain-driven-design, scramble

In my application which is being designed with DDD(domain driven design) pattern with 'laravel-data' library, and so logic related to validation is in a separate action class and that's why scramble cannot recognise it and generate any documentation.[SCRAMBLE POST REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp7lm.png)

Is it possible to validate calling 'rules' method but in different class and in a different directory[THE 'RULES' METHOD OF BRANCH-DATA.PHP FILE WHICH IS LOCATED IN 'APP/DOMAINS/BRANCH/DATA-TRANSFER-OBJECTS'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmXd1.png)